# Creating a moving object when user presses a key (Java)

Tags: java, animation, acm-java-libraries

The idea of my program is to create a picture and have that picture move up in a graphical window, which is exactly what the `rollBall()` method does. The method works when I put the `rollBall()` method in the `run()` method. But the issue lies it cannot run when I put the `rollBall()` method inside the `keyPressed()` method.

I am using the `acm.jar` library as it is a useful tool for creating java graphical program much easier.

Could someone please point me in the right direction.

This is my code...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import acm.graphics.GImage;
import acm.graphics.GOval;
import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;
import acm.util.RandomGenerator;

public class BallDrop extends GraphicsProgram {

    /** width and height of application window in pixels */
    public static final int APPLICATION_WIDTH = 900;
    public static final int APPLICATION_HEIGHT = 768;

    private static final double GRAVITY = 1;

    /** Radius of the ball in pixels */
    private static final int BALL_RADIUS = 50;
    private static final int WIDTH = APPLICATION_WIDTH;

    public void run() {         
        setSize(APPLICATION_WIDTH, APPLICATION_HEIGHT);
        addKeyListeners();
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){ 
        char linkMoveRightKey = e.getKeyChar();
        if(linkMoveRightKey == 'z'){
            rollBall();
        }   
     }

     private void rollBall(){
         setup_Ball();          
         game_Loop();
     }

    private void setup_Ball(){
         pic = new GImage("link.png");
         add(pic,gameBallInitialLocationX, gameBallInitialLocationY);
    }

    private void game_Loop(){
         while(pic.getX() > 0 ){            
              move_Ball();
              pause(DELAY);
         }
    }

    private void move_Ball() {
         ballVelocityX = 0;
         ballVelocityY -= GRAVITY;
         pic.move(ballVelocityX, ballVelocityY);
    }

    private RandomGenerator rgen = RandomGenerator.getInstance();
    private GImage pic;
    private int gameBallInitialLocationX = 500;
    private int gameBallInitialLocationY = 500;
    private int ballVelocityX = (int) rgen.nextDouble(3.0, 5.0);
    private int ballVelocityY =10;
    private static final int DELAY = 50;
 }
```

Comment: never heard about `acm` library but I have been using my own package developed in all these years from scratch. Did you read the manual whether you need to `refresh` any containers after you move with `pic.move(ballVelocityX  ,ballVelocityY);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just read the manual and it is my understanding that you are calling the wrong method:

Instead of calling `run()` method, define the `init()` method.

Also the `setup_Ball()` should be inside `init()` and not inside `rollBall()`  - You only want to initialize the ball when the program starts and not when every time the key is pressed.

So instead of `run()` define `init()`  and also remove `setup_Ball()` from `rollBall()` method :

```
public void init() {
    setSize(APPLICATION_WIDTH, APPLICATION_HEIGHT);
    setup_Ball();
    addKeyListeners();
}
```

Note: You can use the `run()` method when you want some animation to appear when the program starts without waiting for key to be pressed. In that case, you can call the appropriate methods in `run()`

Comment: Also see that, when you remove `setup_Ball()` from the `rollBall()` method, then a redundancy occurs with - `rollBall()` and `game_Loop()`. You can just implement the method routines in one of these and call that method in `keyPressed()`

Comment: You can choose my answer as your solution. Don't know whether that require reps. Thanks